# Python paramiko is not giving complete output and I believe session is closing unexpectedly

Tags: python, paramiko

Environment: 
Python: 2.7.6 
Paramiko: 1.13.0
Target SSH Server: Cisco MDS NX-OS 6.2(3)

Code:

```
import paramiko
import StringIO
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("switchname", username="username", password="password")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("term length 0")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("show zoneset active")    
t = stdout.read()
ssh.close()

for line in StringIO.StringIO(t):
    line = line.replace("\n","")
    print line
```

It is only producing few lines of output instead of the entire output. If I modify above code and add one more ssh.exec_command like shown below.

Code:

```
import paramiko
import StringIO
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("switchname", username="username", password="password")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("term length 0")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("show zoneset active")    
stdin2, stdout2, stderr2 = ssh.exec_command("show version ")    
t = stdout.read()
ssh.close()

for line in StringIO.StringIO(t):
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        print line
```

It produce following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paramiko_issue.py", line 15, in <module>
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("show zoneset active")
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/paramiko/client.py", line 307, in exec_command
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 543, in open_session
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 607, in open_channel
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: SSH session not active
```

I would really appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying query information of off Cisco MDS switches. Information such as flogi database, active zonesets, etc..